# How do I sign out or switch Firebase account in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have separate Google accounts that I use for work and personal things.

In Android Studio, I clicked "App Quality Insights". It asked me to log in and opened a browser, and I accidentally logged in to the wrong account.

Now in Android Studio the App Quality Insights tab just displays an authorization error. So I need to correct my mistake by logging out or switching accounts, but for some reason the button to do this isn't obvious to me. Where is it?